# Python Variable Understanding

Tags: python, if-statement

I was writing this code and I can't seem to get it to work correctly.
There's no Syntax errors so I'm clear on that.
It just is not giving me the correct output I want.

Here's the code :

[image: CLICK HERE FOR THE CODE IMAGE]

This is the out put I get when x = 5 :
Big!
Done!

This is the output I get when x = 1
Small!
Done!

This is what I get when x = anything other than 1 or 5
Done!

What I want it to do is when x = anything between 1-5 to output Small! then Done!
Or if it is between 5-infinity to output Big! then Done! but if the number is not 1 or 5 it just outputs Done!
What changes should I do to my code?

Comment: when you say between 1-5 you want to include 5 also right?
and when you  say 5 - infinity you actually means between 6 to infinity right?

Comment: if you meant the above mentioned scenario.
`try:
  x=int(input("enter a number: "))
  if x >=0 or x<=5:
    print("Small")
    print("Done")
  elif x>=6:
    print("big")
    print("Done")
except ValueError:
  print("Done")

`
here the block of code is written in try block, why i have written in try block if someone enter something which is not number then program will not crash and raise a exception.

Comment: @James It's easier for reviewers if you post the code inline as text instead of linking to an image.

Comment: @user13427216 I know that now. I couldent 2 days ago beacuse my Karma was not up.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 5
if x in range(6):
    print('Small')
elif x >=6 :
    print('Big')
print('Done')
```

Try this. The range function checks if the number is in between 0 and 6 i.e 0 to 5. Anything lesser than 0 will be ignored

The problem with your code is that you're just checking two conditions `if x== 5` and `if x == 1`. The print statements will be executed only if this condition is satisfied.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by a user in the previous answer, what you need to implement is an if-else ladder and use logical operator for the case when your output is specifically either 1 OR 5

```
x=6 # You can replace this by a user defined input using input()
if x==5 or x==1:
    print("Done!")
elif x<5:
    print("Small!")
    print("Done!")
elif x>5:
    print("Big!")
    print("Done!")
else:
    print("Enter a valid number!")
```

I checked with various test cases like 1, 5 , numbers between 1 and 5 and numbers greater than 5 and all seem to work fine.

Here's a sample output
[image: Output]

Comment: how do you make those boxes for the code? thats why i put i picture in so it would be easier to read

Comment: how would i make a user defined imput? if you read my post again, i said im a very early beginner. and to explain more clearly. thank you for helping out. also a tip : if you are writing code put spaces inbetween certant things. like if your writing for it to have a certant variable is true print something. something liek this: if x == 5 print('large'). it makes it easeir to read.

Comment: Something on these lines: `print('Enter your number:')`
`x = input()` This will store the number typed by user in variable `x`

Comment: i found an error in your code. on line 5 the syntax error is < is not supported for instances   of 'str' and 'int'. or here's the entier error :   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Forget what i said. i was using PyScripter for my IDE. I tested it in the python IDE that is included with the python installation and i got no tracebacks. do you know anything about PyScripter to see what the issue is? it is using python 3.7.9 for the imperter.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code above in your pyscripter or did you manually type the whole thing out. The latter shouldnt have given any errors. Many tiumes due to change of typeof encoding like utf-8 etc might vary depending onyour scripting IDE Anyways I m glad you got it working on a different IDE. Do consider upvoting my answer and selecting it as the best one so that the question answered is complete!

Comment: Also you asked about the boxes of code: In order to that, type your code as you would normally do and then select all the code and press `ctrl+k` to make it as a code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `if-else` ladder to achieve this

```
def determine_size(inp):
    if inp == 1 or inp == 5:
       print("Done")
    elif 0 <= inp < 5:
       print("Small")
       print("Done")
    elif inp > 6:
       print("Big")
       print("Done")
    else:
       print("Negative Input")

>>> determine_size(0)
Small
Done
>>> determine_size(100)
Big
Done
>>> determine_size(60)
Big
Done
>>> 
>>> determine_size(3)
Small
Done
>>> determine_size(4)
Small
Done
```

You can also play around with the `if-else` statements per your objectives

Comment: i have not realy learned the def variable yet. like i said im a very early beginner. but thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 40

# at first check if x is greater than 1 and less than 5.
# Only then it is between 1 and 5.
if x >=1 and x<=5:
    print('Small!')
# Now chek if x is greater than 5
elif x>5:
    print('Big!')
print('Done!')
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you meant the above mentioned scenario mentioned in comment**

```
    try:
      x=int(input("enter a number: "))
      if x >=0 or x<=5:
        print("Small")
        print("Done")
      elif x>=6:
        print("big")
        print("Done")
    except ValueError:
        print("Done")
```

here the block of code is written in try block, why i have written in try block if someone enter something which is not number **then program will not crash** and `raise a exception`.

if you are not familiar with elif syntax, we can have simple construction like this :-

```
try:
  x=int(input("enter a number: "))
  if x >=0 and x<=5:
    print("Small")
    print("Done")
  else:
    print("big")
    print("Done")
except ValueError:
  print("Done")
```

Here all I have done is to change the logical operator from `or` to `and`.

Comment: You have an accidental indent on line 1. On the first code block

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but does my solution helped you?

Comment: yes it does. and there is no accidental indent, i dident know try : was part of the script. thanks for the help.

Comment: if that was helpful, do accept it as an answer, so that it may help others in the future :)